# Redefine Macro in existing C library

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Let's say that I have some code as follows:

```
L - A common library (source) (via svn:extern)
X - My project
Y - A static library (source) (via svn:extern) compiled with X and depends on L
```

Inside of `L` there is a macro that is extensively in code in `X` and `Y`

```
#define FOO() printf("Hello World\n")
```

I want to change it to

```
#define FOO() printf("===> Hello World <===")
```

Now, I know that in my code, `X`, I can do:

```
#ifdef FOO
    #undef FOO
    #define FOO() printf("===> Hello World <===")
#endif
```

which will work fine for `X`, but doesn't help for any code in `Y` and compiling.  I could modify `Y` or `L`'s code locally, but then I can't check in my modifications as it might break other project's expectations of what `FOO` does.

Is it possible to modify the macro via the command line, sort of in the same vain as `-D`?  If so, then I could change the behavior in my Makefiles and anyone that checks out `X` will have access to the improved `FOO`. The problem with using `-D` is that it will define the macro function *before* `X` and `Y` `#include` L's macro, which will then cause a macro redefinition warning (and subsequently not the macro I want).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ he said why that's not an option.

Comment: precompile header and/or include directive may help, but it is a hack.

Comment: How would the precompile header work?

Comment: Do you want *`L`* itself to also use your alternative definition of `FOO()` in the context of its usage by `X` and `Y`, or should just the direct uses by `X` and `Y` be modified?

Comment: Well `L` is the base reference, so really they're kind of the same thing.  Ultimately I'd say that I want `L` to use it, thus if something in `Y` called `BAR` in `L` that it'd pick up the new implementation (which I think would happen anyways)

Comment: Those were typos.  Fixed

Comment: suggest create a header file that only changes that one macro.  for the source files where that macro is to be changed, #include the new header file after the header file that originally set the macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that L uses header guards,
you may do something like

in *l_improved.h*

```
#ifndef L_IMPROVED_H
#define L_IMPROVED_H

#include "L.h"

#ifdef FOO
    #undef FOO
    #define FOO() printf("===> Hello World <===");
#endif

#endif
```

and then add:

```
-include l_improved.h
```

in your gcc compiler flags.

From [gcc Preprocessor-Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options):

`-include file`: Process file as if #include "file" appeared as the first line of the primary source file.

Flag may be different if you use an other compiler.

Comment: Brilliant.  I'm going to check this out.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best overall fix is to modify the definition inside `L`, like this:

```
#ifndef FOO
  #define FOO() printf("Hello World\n")
#endif
```

You can check in this change without breaking anybody else's code, and it's then easy to override the definition of `FOO` from the command line or from within a makefile.

Comment: True, but the problem is that I am not the owner of the `L` library, so making changes to it will either be impossible or potentially very cumbersome since it is so widely used.

Comment: Oh, OK - in your question you seemed to be implying that you could check in changes if they don't break other projects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do that other than manipulating `Y` files before building them (like appending the code you wrote).

This is really pretty straightforward and could be done with a `make` command turning your files into say `Y_modified.cpp`, and then making all of the build use the modified version. That way you could treat them as half-built files, and gain all benefits of incremental builds.

A single `Y.cpp` including `L.h` will turn into one translation unit that you can't really inject anything into after the preprocessor has ran.